# Can I pass a variable between a github action and a java program vice versa?

Tags: java, github, action

I have a java program that I need to run in github actions. This java program will generate a number that is needed for part two.

For part two I need to pass another github actions job that number that was generated by the java program.

Is this possible? Ideally I'd like to be able to set and use environment variables

I have tried googling and looking for other information but am yet to find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated